# line-level audio into an iPhone headset jack?

Tags: audio, impedance, iphone

What level and/or impedance matching (or pre-amp) circuits should be used to send a line-level audio signal into the mic input ring of an iPhone headset jack with minimal distortion and/or loss?

Comment: Impedance matching is not used in audio: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/6846/how-important-is-impedance-matching-in-audio-applications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line levels are 0.5-2.0V range.  Mic inputs are expecting millivolts.  You just need what is called an L-pad attenuator.  Your drop should be 40-50 dB.

If you are using a consumer line level, you will need about 40 dB attenuation.  (Professional audio line input would need about 50 dB.)

[image: L-pad attenuator schematic]

Attenuation in dB = 20 * log10((R1 + R2) / R2)

Try R1 = 10k and R2 = 100.

If you get accurate measurements of your line source and a know good mic signal for the iPhone, you will be able to calculate more accurate values.  Or you can put a 500 ohm trimmer resistor in place of R2 to allow varying of the signal if the line out doesn't have adjustment.

Comment: I assume that DC coupling is probably OK.  Or should there be some series caps to avoid potential ground loops in case the phone is somehow grounded?

Comment: You could use coupling caps or a 1:1 audio transformer if you have issues with DC coupling.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you mean the inputs through the Left/Right inputs, in the 30-pin connector.  I've tried to find that info.  At least you don't need an analog to digital converter.

If you mean to use the mic ring on the 4-way plug, there is sensing voltage to be aware of.  It has to do with the typical volume/mute controls, for inline mics in headsets typically used with the iPhone.  I learned this, due to needing to match a low-impedance guitar pickup, to that mic input.  One circuit, for my use, is described at:
http://groupdiy.com/index.php?topic=46767.0
and the diagram can be downloaded at:
https://imageshack.com/f/ghiphonemicinputj

[image]